# Get value from function then make it global

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, multer

How can I get the value from inside the function to use it when posting data to database? Here I want to make the value of imageName inside the `multer.diskStorage` to be global so I can use it when posting the path to database

```
var imageName;
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/assets/images');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/)) {
            var err = new Error();
            err.code = 'filetype';
            return cb(err);
        } else {
            imageName = Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname;
            cb(null, imageName);
        }
    }
});

router.post('/newsfeeds', parser.single("myfile"), function (req, res) {

    newsfeed.path = imageName;
    newsfeed.save(function (err) {
    });
});
```

Comment: Does your `var storage = multer.diskStorage({ ...` execute when you hit the `/newsfeeds` endpoint?

Comment: its undefined for now

Comment: So does your `var storage = multer.diskStorage({...})` code execute before the `router.post(`/newsfeeds`....)` gets called?

Comment: actually this is my problem, newsfeeds gets called first then multer

Comment: Then try making a function that does the multer part, and then `return` the `imageName` variable or value from the new function. Then call that function inside your newsfeeds block.

Comment: Happy to help, If my answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.@Godshand

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to implement `multer`. You can use `upload` as a function or as a middleware, I use it as a function because it allows me a more detailed handling of errors.

It was not necessary a global variable, in this case at the moment that multer processes the image fills the `req.file` property with the information of the image, as we overwrite the function `filename` now in `req.file.filename` this is the custom value that we need.

```
const multer = require('multer');

const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/assets/images');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/)) {
            var err = new Error();
            err.code = 'filetype';
            return cb(err);
        } else {
            const imageName = Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname;
            cb(null, imageName);
        }
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: multerStorage }).single('myfile');


router.post('/newsfeeds',(req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err || !req.file) {
            // An error occurred while loading the image.
            return res.status(400);
        }
        newsfeed.path = req.file.filename;
        newsfeed.save(function (err) {
        });
    });
});
```

> Here you can find a table with the rest of the properties of the image
>   that you have after `multer` processes the image. [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#api)

Comment: still doesn't work, it saves the image to folder but no output in my database

Comment: @Godshand In the code that you published you don't declare a value for `newsfeed` maybe that is the problem, but what you were asking is solved with my code getting the name of the image in `req.file.filename` without the need for a global variable.

Comment: @Godshand I have updated my answer with the name of the entry field of the image `myfile`, I hope this can help you.

Comment: @Godshand If my answer was useful to you, you can accept it or qualify it so other users with a similar problem can find a solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables tend to be frowned upon in the programming community, so you should first ask yourself if it's really what you want to do.

If you do decide it's the best approach, though, in Node you can attach a property to the `global` variable.  In the browser, you can attach it to `window`.

As for your issue with the order of execution (from the OP's comments), you can add a `Promise` instead of a value to the global scope.  Then, anytime you want that value, call `.then()` on your value, or run it in an `async function` with `await`.